# difference between passing parameters in function using call by value and call by reference

Tags: c++, recursion, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, call-by-value

What is the return value of f(p, p), if the value of p is initialised to 5 before the call? Note that the first parameter is passed by reference, whereas the second parameter is passed by value.

```
int f(int& x, int c)
{
  c = c — 1;
  if (c = = 0)
    return 1;

  x = x + 1;
  return f(x, c) * x;
}
```

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value/430958

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: The code is invalid.

Comment: @CiaPan - why do you say the code is invalid? It is fine, the only limitation is you cannot pass a integer literal as `x` (and you have to remove the Unicode characters and replace them with ASCII)

Comment: I say it is invalid because two consecutive `=` operators in `if (c = = 0)` do not fit C++ grammar.

Comment: Yes, you are correct there, but since the em-dash `'-'` was a Unicode character -- that looked more like a copy/paste from web error than intentional.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  I know. And may be my comment was too short, and unkind due to that. But, whatever the origin of the code was, when fed to a compiler the code will appear invalid. Anyway, the question looks like a test problem to me. The _'Note that...'_ part sounds like it was said by a teacher, someone who knows precisely what the trick is in the code and what the answer should be.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect UB here, as you have no guarantee whether the `x` value will be fetched for multiplication *before* or *after* execution of the recursive call to `f`.